# How Paypal button work and build one from scratch

Tags: button, paypal

I would like to know how paypal button works in detail and create my own "alternative" to paypal button.
Could someone let me know any code which would help me create such a button from scratch 
with its security?

Answer (score 0):

You need a hosted button which created from button factory located under your PayPal account. This is the easiest way. Read [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/buy-now-button)